# syntax error - unexpected tASSOC

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8.7

I am trying to learn some ruby http request response code from this tutorial -

http://danknox.github.io/2013/01/27/using-rubys-native-nethttp-library/

Code so far -

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("http://api.random.com")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

# Continuing our example from above

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/search?question=somequestion")
response = http.request(request)

response.code
=>"200"
response.body
=> # Raw response body would go here needing to be parsed
```

error -

```
Test.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting $end
=> "200"
  ^
```

I don't know why this happens. I removed the space and the error remains. I saw 3-4 Stack overflow posts on this, but they did not help.

Comment: What is `=> "200"`?  It kinda looks like something cut-and-pasted from `irb`.  Edit: ah, judging from the linked article, that seems to be the case, although the author didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should comment out the two lines in your code that start with `=>`.  Those are meant to be comments explaining what the return value of the method should be, but somehow they got uncommented and the Ruby interpreter tried to parse them as code.

```
puts response.code  # => "200"
puts repsonse.body  # => Raw response body
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am now getting an error uninitialized constant HTTPSuccess (NameError). Not sure if I should make an extra question for this.

Comment: Yeah, an extra question would be appropriate.